# Probability of three identical digits on a four-digit digital clock?

Tags: probability, time

On a digital clock showing 00:00 to 23:59, what is the probability of having exactly three identical digits?

Comment: Does 4 identical digits also count? And do they count once or 3 times?

Comment: @CSM, I would say the question is already clear.  4 isn't "exactly 3".

Comment: **Depends is there a leading 0 or not, so is 7am represented by `07:00` or `7:00`?**

Comment: ThomasL: well **is there a leading 0 or not**, so is 7am represented by `07:00` or `7:00`??? You should clarify things like that promptly. Otherwise the question has multiple solutions.

Comment: @smci: yes, there is a leading zero - I refer to a digital clock, which always shows 4 digits.

Comment: @ThomasL: No, I have seens tons of digital clocks, but some show a leading 0, whereas some show leading blank instead of 0 - "4-digit digital clock" is not an unambiguous format - I repeatedly pointed that out to you. Your title disagrees with your question body.

Comment: @smci: ok, I did not know that digital clocks may not show leading zeros... so to clarify, my question was intended to always assume 4 digits on the display. Maybe out of interest, what would you see as 00:00?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Number of qualifying times:

> 00:0# (9)
>  00:#0 (5)
>  0#:00 (9)
>  #0:00 (2)
>  11:1# (9)
>  11:#1 (5)
>  1#:11 (9)
>  #1:11 (2)
>  22:2# (9)
>  22:#2 (5)
>  2#:22 (3)
>  #2:22 (2)
>  #3:33 (3)
>  #4:44 (2)
>  #5:55 (2)
>  Total: 76 qualifying times

Probability:

> 76/1440 = 19/360, approximately 5.28%

Comment: More elegant and correct than my attempt. I had a feeling I was missing a few big sets like 00:0# and 22:2#..

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** There was a mistake in my original answer. I fixed it and now my answer agrees with (and essentially duplicates) Daniel Mathias's answer.

Qualifying times:

> 00:01
>  00:02
>  00:03
>  00:04
>  00:05
>  00:06
>  00:07
>  00:08
>  00:09
>  00:10
>  00:20
>  00:30
>  00:40
>  00:50
>  01:00
>  01:11
>  02:00
>  02:22
>  03:00
>  03:33
>  04:00
>  04:44
>  05:00
>  05:55
>  06:00
>  07:00
>  08:00
>  09:00
>  10:00
>  10:11
>  11:01
>  11:10
>  11:12
>  11:13
>  11:14
>  11:15
>  11:16
>  11:17
>  11:18
>  11:19
>  11:21
>  11:31
>  11:41
>  11:51
>  12:11
>  12:22
>  13:11
>  13:33
>  14:11
>  14:44
>  15:11
>  15:55
>  16:11
>  17:11
>  18:11
>  19:11
>  20:00
>  20:22
>  21:11
>  21:22
>  22:02
>  22:12
>  22:20
>  22:21
>  22:23
>  22:24
>  22:25
>  22:26
>  22:27
>  22:28
>  22:29
>  22:32
>  22:42
>  22:52
>  23:22
>  23:33

Number of qualifying times:

> 76

Probability of having exactly three identical digits:

> 76 / 1440 = approximately 5.28%

Answer (score 2):

I came up with a solution using [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/)

```
require 'time'

MINUTES_IN_A_DAY = 1_439

time                = Time.parse('00:00')
three_of_same_count = 0

MINUTES_IN_A_DAY.times do
  counts = time.strftime('%H%M').each_char.with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |c, o|
    o[c] += 1
  end

  three_of_same_count += 1 if counts.values.max == 3

  time += 60 # seconds
end

puts "Number of occurrences #{three_of_same_count}"
puts "#{((three_of_same_count.to_f / MINUTES_IN_A_DAY) * 100).round(3)}% of all occurrences"
```

Output:

> Number of occurrences 76
>  5.281% of all occurrences

Comment: I think your "minutes in a day" is off... this is the "seconds in a day" value... therefor your total number is times 60 to large... but as your overall count is off the same amount your percentage is ok after all...

Answer (score 1):

Let me give a differnt interpretation: Ther times of interest are

> 0:00
>  1:11
>  2:22
>  3:33
>  4:44
>  5:55
>  No other time formats exist that conain exactly 3 same digits.

Total number of possible digit combinations:

> 24 * 60 = 1440

Total probability

> 6 / 1440 = 1 / 240 = 0.417%

---

Edit: Explanation for the selection of possible times:

> In general we are looking for any time that consists of 3 digits only. Thus any time later than (0)9:59 is out of scope. (The times 10:00 and onwards have all 4 digits.)
>  The remining pairs are 0:00, 1:11, ..., 5:55, 6:66,..., 9:99 (theoretically). Obviously the cases 6:66 until 9:99 are not plausible as minutes past 59 are not valid.

Thank you @MacGyver88 for the hint. I seem to have been to tierd to think straight ahead.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Puzzling.  Can you please explain why those are the only 2 options?  I may be the only one, but I don't understand unless your clock fell and the display was broken somehow.  I'm all for that but you may want to elaborate a little bit.

Comment: The problem specifically states the numbers start at 00:00 not 0:00 so looks like the leading zero is always present, so according to your logic the probability would have to be 0%!

Comment: You are right, I thought not of that.

Answer (score 1):

> There are four digits, but **the 1st and 3rd digits are constrained to only be 0..5**. Hence to get three identical digits D, D would have to be in range D=0..5
>  And there are 24*60 legal (four-digit) times, in total.

#### **Case a) when there is a leading zero digit, so e.g. 7am is represented as `07:00` not `7:00`**:

> Then 10/24 of the time the first digit is '0', 10/24 it's '1', and 4/24 it's '2'. So 20/24 of the time it's '0' or '1' and 4/24 it's '2'.

> P(3 identical digits) = ([number of legal times with three identical digits where first digit is 0 or 1] + [number of legal times with first digit 2]) / 24*60
>  ...and the rest is combinatorics and algebra

#### **Case b) when there isn't a leading zero digit, so e.g. 7am is represented as `7:00` not `07:00`**:

> Then 10/24 of the time the first digit doesn't exist (so there are only three digits), 10/24 it's '1', and 4/24 it's '2'.

> P(3 identical digits) = ([number of legal times without first digit, with three identical digits] + [number of legal times with three identical digits where first digit is 1] + [number of legal times with three identical digits where first digit is 2]) / 24*60
> and the rest is combinatorics and algebra